# Абстрактный класс Figure в js

Tags: javascript, ооп

Создать абстрактный класс Figure с методами вычисления периметра, а также
методом, выводящим информацию о фигуре на экран. Создать производные классы:
прямоугольник, круг , треугольник со своими методами
вычисления периметра. Создать массив n фигур и вывести полную
информацию о фигурах на экран.
То есть у нас есть класс figure и он будет классом предком для классов `Circle`, `Triangle`, `Rectangle` и в каждом из этих классов мы должны создать метод который будет наследовать пустой метод `calculatePerimetr` из класса `Figure` в другие классы ,а там уже реализовываться ?Правильно ли я вообще сделал и понял.Но при проверке `perimetr == underfined`

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
 <style>
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
<script>
  class Figure{
    constructor(x,y){
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }

  calculatePerimetr(){
   return  this.perimetr;
  }
  }

class Rectangle extends Figure{
   constructor(x,y,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4){
  super(x,y);
  this.x2 = x2;
  this.y2 = y2;
  this.x3 = x3;
  this.y3 = y3;
  this.x4 = x4;
  this.y4 = y4;
}

calculatePerimetr(){
  let perimetr = super.calculatePerimetr();
  perimetr = (Math.abs( (this.x - this.x2) + (this.y - this.y2) ) + Math.abs( (this.x2 - this.x3) + (this.y2 - this.y3) )) * 2;
    //this.perimetr = perimetr;
    return perimetr;

}

calculateSquare(){
  let square = Math.abs(this.y - this.y2) * Math.abs(this.x2 - this.x3);
  this.square = square;
  return square;
 }

 get Perimetr(){
  return this.perimetr;
 }
}

class Circle extends Figure{
  constructor(x,y,x2,y2){  // x и y центр окружности, а x2,y2 точка в пространстве 
    super(x,y);
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
  }

  calculatePerimetr(){
    super.calculatePerimetr();
    let radius = Math.abs( (this.x - this.x2) + (this.y - this.y2) );
    let perimetr = Math.Pi * 2 * radius;
    this.perimetr = perimetr;
    return perimetr;
  }
}

class Triangle extends Figure{
  constructor(x,y,x2,y2,x3,y3){
   super(x,y);
   this.x2 = x2;
   this.y2 = y2;
   this.x3 = x3;
   this.y3 = y3;
 }

 calculatePerimetr(){
  super.calculatePerimetr();
   let sideFirst = Math.sqrt(((this.x2 - this.x) * (this.x2 - this.x)) + ((this.y2 - this.y) * (this.y2 - this.y)));
   let sideSecond = Math.sqrt(((this.x3 - this.x) * (this.x3 - this.x)) + ((this.y3 - this.y) * (this.y3 - this.y)));
   let sideThird = Math.sqrt(((this.x3 - this.x2) * (this.x3 - this.x2)) + ((this.y3 - this.y2) * (this.y3 - this.y2)));
   let perimetr = (this.sideFirst + this.sideSecond + this.sideThird);
   this.perimetr = perimetr;
  return perimetr 
 }
}

let figures = [
  new Rectangle(4,2,4,8,12,8,12,4),
  new Circle(6,6,6,12),
  new Triangle(1,1,2,3,4,1),
];
</script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: зачем вызывать `super.calculatePerimetr()` если внутри него ничего не вычисляется, а возвращаемое значение игнорируется?

Comment: Нужно создать класс Figure с вычислениями периметра. Но у каждой фигуры периметр будет вычисляться по разным формулам. Зачем нам тогда класс Figure в данном случае

Comment: А он и не нужен :-)

Comment: Но есть случай в котором он нужен ?

Comment: Если только попробовать вынести в него общую часть, но в данном случае - у тебя ее нет

Comment: Как мне тогда можно вывести массив этих  объектов если каждый из них представляет другой класс.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101993/discussion-between-grundy-and-).